# same query in jpa and oracle client , different result

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jpa

could it happen that running the same query in entityManager.createNativeQuery (JPA)and in any oracle client (SQL) give different results??

It's happening me using the following query:

```
SELECT FITE_INSTID,
  fite_grado,
  SUM(lenguajeP) as lenguajeP,
  SUM(lenguajeG) as lenguajeG,
  SUM(lenguajeX) as lenguajeX,
  SUM(matematicasP) as matematicasP,
  SUM(matematicasG) as matematicasG,
  SUM(matematicasX) as matematicasX,
  SUM(cienciasP) as cienciasP,
  SUM(cienciasG) as cienciasG,
  SUM(cienciasX) as cienciasX,
  SUM(pensamientoP) as pensamientoP, 
  SUM(pensamientoG) as pensamientoG, 
  SUM(pensamientoX) as pensamientoX
  FROM
(SELECT f.FITE_INSTID,
  f.fite_anio,
  f.fite_grado,    
 (CASE WHEN f.FITE_TIPO_REPORTE_L IN ('08') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS lenguajeP,
 (CASE WHEN f.FITE_TIPO_REPORTE_L IN ('05') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS lenguajeG,
 (CASE WHEN f.FITE_TIPO_REPORTE_L NOT IN ('05','08') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS lenguajeX,
 (CASE WHEN f.FITE_TIPO_REPORTE_M IN ('08') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS matematicasP,
 (CASE WHEN f.FITE_TIPO_REPORTE_M IN ('05') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS matematicasG,
 (CASE WHEN f.FITE_TIPO_REPORTE_L NOT IN ('05','08') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS matematicasX,
 (CASE WHEN f.FITE_TIPO_REPORTE_C IN ('08') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cienciasP,
 (CASE WHEN f.FITE_TIPO_REPORTE_C IN ('05') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cienciasG,
 (CASE WHEN f.FITE_TIPO_REPORTE_L NOT IN ('05','08') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cienciasX,
 (CASE WHEN f.FITE_TIPO_REPORTE_D IN ('08') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS pensamientoP,
 (CASE WHEN f.FITE_TIPO_REPORTE_D IN ('05') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS pensamientoG,
 (CASE WHEN f.FITE_TIPO_REPORTE_L NOT IN ('05','08') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS pensamientoX
FROM Fichatecnica f 
WHERE 
  f.FITE_ESTADO=1 and  f.fite_instid is not null and f.fite_anio in (?,?,?,?)  and f.fite_instid=?) GROUP BY FITE_INSTID,
  fite_grado
```

the result in column matematicasP is 5 using jpa, but in sql the result is 3.

Does anyone has had this kind of problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't make sense.  Are you sure that the state of the database isn't changing under you?  Could the correct answer have been 3 when you executed in SQL and 5 when you executed in JPA, and both be correct?

Second, are you sure you're passing the same bind variable values in each case?

Comment: Actually, I used admin permissions to see the query my JPA session was launching. Nevertheless, no changes in db state or bind variables. :S

Answer (score 0):

To solve it.. I had to reset Oracle DB.
After it, oracle client (sql developer and sql plus) show me the answer I was looking for.
I have no idea why doing so solved the issue.